# Apache authentication on a single port/subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2

I have 3 webapps running on my machine on different ports like:

```
xxx.domain.com:8080
yyy.domain.com:8181
zzz.domain.com:8282
```

If I add to my httpd.conf:

```
<Location "/">
AuthUserFile /my/file/with/users
AuthName "This is a protected area"
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
</Location>
```

The authentication works fine, but I want to be able to have Apache authentication only when the user enters "xxx.domain.com" and not yyy/zzz, is it possible without using .htaccess files and the `<Location>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, use virtual hosts:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it by putting in the Directory directive (into VirtualHost) instead of using .htaccess.